# How to fix ' Manifest merger failed with multiple errors,' error?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, android-design-library

I was connecting FIREBASE to my current working AndroidStudio project and after implementing all the libraries, I am stuck at an error.

> "ERROR: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs"

What should i do..?

This is error , what i am getting

> Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined but found IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support', myArtifactId='cardview-v7', myVersion='28.0.0', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} and IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.swiperefreshlayout', myArtifactId='swiperefreshlayout', myVersion='1.0.0', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} incompatible dependencies less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible[enter ima[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3eqr.png)ge description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRTlj.png)

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

This problem should occur from using both androidx and android support libraries at the same time. Migrate the whole project to `AndroidX` by using `Refactor` > `Migrate to AndroidX` from the IDE. After migrating to AndroidX, recheck if you have these two lines in your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Setting these two gradle plugin flags to true means that Android Plugin will use appropriate AndroidX library instead of support Library & will rewrite their binaries. For knowing more how to migrate an entire project to AndroidX, please follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Comment: Thanks aaksh , but i have already done this following steps. but still i'm facing the same errors

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the 'build.gradle (Module:app)'
2. Select Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX
3. After processing, click 'Do Refactor'. This button will be in below left corner of IDE (Look carefully).
4. Update library versions to latest versions in build.gradle (Module:App). Alt+Enter will help you out.
5. Sync Gradle and I hope this will solve the problem as it solved mine.

I am also a newbie in android app development.

Comment: Thanks Abdur , Already done But still facing the same error. Actually My android studio project has been installed on my android device ...but its not Running..